# How to print specific index of one list, into another list?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list

```
book_list
```

which lists several books and their details such as title genre etc

```
P.G. Wodehouse, Right Ho Jeeves, hb, Penguin, 10.99, 5, fiction
A. Pais, Subtle is the Lord, pb, OUP, 12.99, 2, biography
etc
```

I would like to take the title of each book in this list and add the ouput into another list (so I can then sort the titles)

Currently my code prints all the book titles but I cannot manage to add this to another list

```
def option6():
    l = []
    for book in book_list:
        x = print(book[1])

    l.append(x)

    print(sorted(l))
```

This is the ouput

```
 Right Ho Jeeves
 Subtle is the Lord
 The Quotable Einstein
 The Chemical History of a Candle
 Energy and Empire
 Popular Lectures
 The Screwtape Letters
 The Hobbit
 The Four Loves
 Inner Exile
 Natural Theology
[None]
```

Comment: just put `l.append(book[1])` in you loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print` statement returns `None`. Hence, you are appending `None` to the new list. The append statement is out of the `for` loop. Bring it inside the loop

Try the below code

```
def option6():
    l = []
    for book in book_list:
        print(book[1])
        x = book[1]
        l.append(x)
    print(sorted(l))
```

Comment: thank you, how can i make it so that only the sorted list prints however, as right now it prints both the list of unsorted titles and then the sorted titles list.

Comment: Comment the `print` statement inside the `for` loop